# JSON data parsing android

Tags: java, json

This is JSON response I am getting.

I want to select first 45 records response then I want to select next 45 and so on.

How can I parse this data?

Help.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "id": "xxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Something like this I am trying.

```
try {

    JSONObject rob = response.getJSONObject();

    JSONArray array = rob.getJSONArray("data");

    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

        JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);

        Log.d("uid",friend.getString("id"));
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: it would be good to add ,what have you tried so far

Comment: added help I want to shuffle

Comment: now  what do you mean by shuffle

Comment: means first 45 then 45 like that .

Comment: you can make `i` as global variable and first time starts from `0`  , till `45` in loop and next time starts from `45`  and so on

Comment: I got ids . Now I am trying to convert them into comma seperated . I edited with the code I tried.

Comment: one simple way for you is , parse you whole array in some array or arraylist and then simply access the values in array/arraylist using range of indexes

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it without any IDE, it just is an idea and not more. You will need to check and write it correctly.

```
// Fields
final static int ITEMS_PER_REQUEST = 45;
int currentIndex = 0;
// Method body
try {
    JSONObject rob = response.getJSONObject();

    JSONArray array = rob.getJSONArray("data");
    int size = Math.min(array.Length, currentIndex + ITEMS_PER_REQUEST);

    while(currentIndex < size;) {
        JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(currentIndex);
        Log.d("uid",friend.getString("id"));
        ++currentIndex;
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```